# PHP- get the last 6 months from the current date

Tags: php, html, date, web

I am trying to get the last six months from the current date in PHP. It's a simple problem, but my code is not giving the right result.

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= 5; $j++) {
    echo date("F Y", strtotime(" -$j month"));
    echo "<br>";
}
```

And the output is

```
March 2018
March 2018
January 2018
December 2017
December 2017
October 2017
```

I dont understand why `March` is coming twice.

Comment: Probably because going back "one month" from March 30/31 (whatever time zone you might be in, should be either one of those right now) is rather February 30/31-ish ... U no read manual? User comments are full of this stuff, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#107331

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `strototime('-1 month')` doesn't handle correctly the end of month.

You could use the first day of the current month:

```
$dt = strtotime(date('Y-m-01'));
for ($j = 0; $j <= 5; $j++) {
    echo date("F Y", strtotime(" -$j month", $dt));
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Outputs:

```
March 2018
February 2018
January 2018
December 2017
November 2017
October 2017
```